# Android - Azure Live data Stream to cloud

Tags: android, azure, azure-iot-hub

I need a help. I have some sensor data coming into my Android App from a health device, which has to be live streamed to the Azure cloud. Right now i have a button on click event to send the data at that particular time, but i want the continous streaming to happen may be in the background. I think Android Services would be the right choice for this but i am not sure how to implement it for my scenario.could someone help me proceed as i am completely new to this ? Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, based on my understanding, I think you want to send the sensor data of health devices produced via live streaming way from Android App to Azure IoTHub.

However, as I known, there is not live streaming way like websocket way for sending data to Azure IoTHub now. The simple way to send data from Android is using the REST API of [`Http Runtime - Send Device Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/httpruntime/senddeviceevent) without consideration for using any programming languages.

If you want to do that via some more effective ways, Azure IoTHub supports AMQP/MQTT protocols, so you can try to use [Azure IoT Device SDK for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/tree/master/device) which supports Android API 17+ to implement your needs with AMQP or MQTT. There are some sample codes at [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/tree/master/device/iot-device-samples), that you can refer to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Peter,. I have already done the things mentioned by you in the given links. I am actually able to send the data to the IOT hub , but only when the user clicks the button, instead i want all the data that is being recieved by the app to be sent to the iot hub without use interference ( may be a background service ) even when the app is closed. This is my current issue.